# IDE for Machine Learning workflow - AWS SageMaker

Tags: machine-learning, sagemaker

Looks like we don't really use an IDE in any of Machine Learning workflow stages if we use AWS SageMaker.
Entire work is done in jupyter notebook. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter Notebook can be considered an integrated development environment (IDE).

Amazon Web Services (AWS)'s SageMaker is a fully managed, cloud version of Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score -1):

Some ide you can use in your local machine :

1. Spyder
2. Jupyter Notebook
3. Jupyter Lab

Pycharm VSCode also has intregated support for notebook but i would suggest jupyter lab. It's really good

If you want to run on VMs then google colab and kaggle kernel is really good for free.

Comment: How does this relate to AWS Sagemaker?